# How can i get input field value on hitting enter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to get the value from input box when user hit enter.
i do not need any button.
How can i achieve that

**test.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form action="#" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <center>
            <input name="quan" align="middle" type="text" id="quan" placeholder="quan" title="If You Want Change Quantity Then Type Here"  size="4">
    </center>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var model=$('#quan').val();
        console.log(model);
    });                                     
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want that to happen if the user hits enter anywhere on the page, or enter a value then hits enter ?

Comment: you could use an `onChange()` event, but it depends on what you want to do with the value. I would go for a regular `form submit`

Comment: If you set a submit button in form (can be hidden by styling) then pressing enter on input will trigger a synthetic click on this dubmit button and then you would get your value server side depending form action attribute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `keyup()` or `keydown()` function. Appending to it, use `event.keyCode == 13` for getting the value after hitting `enter` button.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="#" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <center>
            <input name="quan" align="middle" type="text" id="quan" placeholder="quan" title="If You Want Change Quantity Then Type Here"  size="4">
    </center>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#quan').keydown(function(event) {
          if (event.keyCode == 13) {
              var model=$('#quan').val();
              alert(model);
              // Use this 'model' variable
          }
      });
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**User's Requirement**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#quan').keydown(function(event) {
          if (event.keyCode == 13) {
              var model=$('#quan').val();
              $.ajax({url:"nextPage.php?model="+model,cache:false,success:function(result){
                    alert("success");
              }});
          }
      });
 });
</script>
```

**nextPage.php** (Create a new page. Make sure, your page name matches with the page name given in `<script></script>`. Both are related.)

```
<?php
$model = $_GET['model'];

//Now, use this '$model' wherever you want to use in this page. 

?>
```

**Success** & **Error**

```
$.ajax({url:"nextPage.php?model="+model,cache:false,success:function(result){
      if(result.status == 'success'){
                alert("success");
      } else if(result.status == 'error') {
                alert("Error");
      }
}});
```

Comment: Party kar
How would i use the javascript variable in php ?

Comment: You want to pass this `model` value to another page or what @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide?

Comment: Yes dear,
what if i want to pass this value to another page or on the same page for using it for sqli query?

Comment: Use Ajax to send this `model` to next page. Wait for few minutes. I will provide you the code for sending it to next page @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide

Comment: Thanks NANA bhai :P
God Bless you

Comment: @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide : Always Welcome `:)` *Salamat Raho, Khush Raho*

Comment: bhai sorry for disturbance !
Mai ne success se agay error likha hay jax mai , kaam ni kar raha ,,
error:function(result){
                    alert("failed");
              }..
Kia issue ho skta hay /

Comment: See **Success & Error** Section @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide

Answer (score 3):

```js
function getVal(ele) {
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        alert(ele.value);        
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeydown="getVal(this)"/>
```

Comment: OP is using jquery, and why you are suggesting him to use a bad practice that is using an inline event handler.

Comment: @Niklesh
What if i want to store this value in a variable for php purposes?

Comment: If you want to post this value then just name it and get this value in another .php file which you will mention in action tag. Can you explain if it is not so.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script>
 $(document).on('keyup','#quan',function(){
 var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
   //Do something
  }
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#quan').keyup(function (e){
            var model=$(this).val();
            if(e.keyCode == 13){
                alert(model)
              }
          })

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( "input" ).keypress(function( event ) {
  if ( event.which == 13 ) {
      alert($(this).val());
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: @Rivdan Shaikh
What if i want to store this value in a variable for php purposes?

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( "input" ).keypress(function( event ) {
  if ( event.which == 13 ) {
      consol.log($(this).val());
  }
});
</script>
```

where 13 is enter key code when you enter it in keyboard you can see the value in console

Comment: What if i want to store this value in a variable for php purposes?

Comment: please check this https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/pass-jquery-value-to-php-variable/10687

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#quan').keyup(function (event) {
          if (event.which === 13) {
                var model = $(this).val();
                console.log(model);
          }
     });
});
```